# Rails does not load /javascript/packs for vue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack

The vue components in the rails app I'm using are not loading. The application works on other peoples computers correctly so I believe it's not an issue with the project itself. I may have not installed the project correctly?

I made sure I had nvm, node installed correctly.

Everything on the side of the rail of things works correctly such as the database ect.

GET http://localhost:3000/packs/vue-app-bootstrapper.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

These are the errors I get.

I also get this error. Not sure what this one means though.

livereload.js?host=localhost:191 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED